# Fetch in javascript, different between mode no-cors, cors and same-origin

Tags: javascript, fetch

I'm pretty sure that I understand what is difference between no-cors and cors but what same-origin means? How do I compare all of them between each other?

Answer (score 0):

Definition of same-origin :

> Two pages have the same origin if the protocol, port (if one is
>   specified), and host are the same for both pages. You'll see this
>   referred to as the "scheme/host/port tuple" at times (where a "tuple"
>   is a set of three components that together comprise a whole).

You can read about it on the MDN website [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: so how to compare it to cors? What's the difference between cors and same-origin?

Comment: Google returns plenty of results, this being a good one to read -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS